# Video inside iframe inside lightbox wordpress

Tags: wordpress, iframe, video, lightbox

I'm using wordpress.

I'm trying to get a video inside iFrame, inside a lightbox. And display it as the (iFrame) video file.

I want to use a video file, as display (instead of a thumbnail).
Then, when you click the video file, it opens up in a lightbox, where you have the ability to play it.

I have no trouble embeding the video inside the iFrame, but I cant get it to behave as I want, because I cant get iFrame to work inside a lightbox/ I havent found a lightbox plugin that lets me do this.

I cant get this to work. Also, I cant use "Form Lightbox"-plugin, as it clashes with Optimizepress. (Im not talking about youtube videos here, I want to be able to embed any video, from any site

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this? Very simple wordpress plug in.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/iframe/

Also, check out the latest version of Worpress. It has a lot of new media embedding features.

Answer (score 0):

[Fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) is a great alternative, that has built in attributes to designate whether you would like it to show an iframe or what have you.

Check out the iframe tutorial on the website and read all about it. Easy to set up and works great!